# How to add some text to a hr tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have some text towards the end of a hr tag and so far I haven't managed to get it working as it should.

I am expecting to have a line --------------------- top  with some text towards the end.
You can see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2BHYr/

Edit:

What i want is:

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__Top

Comment: could you draw something similar to what you expect? not quite sure what you need

Comment: did not quite understand what you wanted, but ended up doing something http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/2BHYr/11/

Comment: Please create an image of the proper output (even in Ms paint) and post it here. We don't entirely understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I only get it working as an absolutely positioned element, but using a `HR`-tag and its title-attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/Cfwmz/

Comment: @feeela even though that's neat and clean, the :after pseudo-selector does not work in most living versions of IE, and does not allow for the text to be made into a link.

Comment: Having a link on that text wasn't requested anywhere. The OP states he/she would like to display "some text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have understood what it is you want. Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fMJm2/2/ (Updated with Version 2 as well.)

HTML:

```
<div class="separator">
    <hr>
    <a href="#top">To Top</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.separator {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.separator hr {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.separator a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-style: italic;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 2px 20px;
}
​
```

In my code, I have wrapped everything in a div with class `separator` for ease.

- .separator gets it's position set to relative in order for more control over the child elements.
- hr gets position absolute and so does the link. This is in order to be able to position the `<a>` tag on top of the `<hr>`.
- The link is set to `right: 0` with a bit of padding, and ends up to the right and on top of the `<hr>`. I believe this is what you want to achieve.

**Version 2:**
Per OP's request, I've re-mixed the above code to work without a `<hr>` tag. Semantically it would make sense with a `<hr>`, but OP's circumstances does not allow for it to be used.

HTML:

```
<div class="separator_v2">
    <a href="#top">To Top</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.separator_v2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: visible;
}
.separator_v2 a {
    margin-top: -12px;
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    float: right;
}​
```

The use of negative margin is what makes this work. Despite popular belief, negative margin is *not* a hack, it's W3C compliant.

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: Oswaldo, the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/2BHYr/11, you mean? Look at the results. Clearly they are radically different. Mine actually uses an <hr> tag and produces the right result.

Comment: I have also updated my original idea.You can see it here. http://jsfiddle.net/2BHYr/17/

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/53vD8/2/

It gives a HR line followed by a link.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>Lines</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layer">
        <div class="line simple"></div>
        <a href="#" class="top_a">Top</a>
    </div>
    <div class="layer">
        <div class="line simple"></div>
        <a href="#" class="top_a">Top</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.layer
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.line.simple
{
    width:90%; 
    height:0px; 
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:1px 0 0 0; 
    float:left;
    margin:15px 0 0px; 
}

.top_a
{ 
    padding-left:5px; 
    font:italic 12px/18px Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for an <hr> yet this solution gets labeled as the one that solved it? Funny...

Comment: @Patrik,i am working within a framework(twitter bootstrap) and if i put in <hr> things are getting a little hairy.

Comment: username002, in that case, you can always substitute <hr> for a span or something. I'll update my answer and the fiddle with that version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a HR tag for this? Try this instead: Put the text in a DIV with width 100%, set the top or bottom border to 1 solid and align the text to the right.

```
.hr-div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 0px 0 1 0
}

<div class="hr-div">Top</div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't change what has already been achieved. My understanding is that the word 'top' should be vertically aligned with the `hr`, not on top of or below it.