# Centering legend in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

### The problem

The problem is that the following works in Chrome, Opera and IE <sup><sub>(!?)</sub></sup> but does not work in Firefox:

```css
fieldset>legend {
  display: table;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

#### Result in Chrome

[image: Result on Chrome]

#### Result in Firefox

[image: Result on Firefox]

### <strike>Solutions</strike> Hacks

There are a few questions around but none have satisfying answers:

```css
/* intended styling */
fieldset>legend {
    display: table;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

fieldset.absolute-fix {
    position: relative;
}
fieldset.absolute-fix>legend {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

fieldset.margin-fix>legend {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}

fieldset.width-fix>legend {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="absolute-fix">
    <legend>Fix with absolute</legend>
    <p>Not centered and inconsitant styling</p>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006871/1185053">Source</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="attribute-fix">
    <legend align="center">Fix with attribute</legend>
    <p>Requires use of depreciated HTML and strongly ties presentation to content.</p>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/19969606/1185053">Source</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="margin-fix">
    <legend>Fix with margin</legend>
    <p>This is unsatisfying because there is a mis-aligned gap in the border and long legends go over several lines.</p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="width-fix">
    <legend>Fix with width</legend>
    <p>This is unsatisfying because there is a gaping hole in the border.</p>
</fieldset>
```

### Question

Is there a way to constantly center `legend` in Firefox, whilst maintaining styling for other browsers?

Comment: Even simpler: `legend { text-align: center; }` for browsers different than Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution uses a Firefox specific selector so we don't need to touch the styling for the other browsers. It uses absolute positioning but uses the `transform` property to center appropriately.

```css
/* indended styling for other browsers */
fieldset>legend {
  display: table;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* FF only */
@media screen and (-moz-images-in-menus: 0) {
  fieldset {
    position: relative;
  }
  fieldset>legend {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -12px; /* depends on font size and border */
    background: white; /* depends on background */
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fix using absolute and transform</legend>
  <p>This seems to work a bit better.</p>
</fieldset>
```

#### Result in Chrome

[image: Result in Chrome]

#### Result in Firefox

[image: Result in Firefox]

Comment: Even simpler: `legend { text-align: center; }` for other browsers. By the way, your solution for Firefox is cross-browser, so you only need this one. (And you can also use `translateX(-50%)`.)

Comment: Ran this code snippet in firefox and doesn't appear to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2023 and still firefox didn't fix this issue. (SO SAD)

Just wanted to give you guys what worked for me which is far simpler than mentioned solutions.

Using absolute positioning definitely works and is the best if you want to have full flexibility on the placement of the `legend` tag. However, In my case, I just wanted the legend to go to the right side of the `fieldset`. I did this:

```
.firefox-legend-fix {
  legend {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Yes, **I am aware that this does not directly answer the question** but as this was the first hit on google, i decided to help others who are struggling with `legend` tag alignment in `firefox`

So, In order to center it you can do `margin-inline: auto;`